# Docker ADD is failing with relative directory

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My docker file has following entry

```
ENV SCPATH /etc/supervisor/conf.d

RUN apt-get -y update

# The daemons
RUN apt-get -y install supervisor
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor

# Supervisor Configuration
ADD ./supervisord/conf.d/* $SCPATH/
```

The directory structure looks like this

```
├── .dockerignore
├── .gitignore
├── Dockerfile
├── Makefile
├── README.md
├── Vagrantfile
├── index.js
├── package.json
└── supervisord
    └── conf.d
        ├── node.conf
        └── supervisord.conf
```

As per my understanding this should work fine as

```
ADD ./supervisord/conf.d/* $SCPATH/
```

Points to a relative path in terms of dockerfile build context.

Still it fails with

> ./supervisord/conf.d : no such file or directory exists.

I am new to docker so might be a very basic thing I am missing. Really appreciate help

Answer (score 0):

What are your [`.dockerignore`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) file contents? Are you sure you did not accidentally exclude something below your `supervisord` directory that the docker daemon needs to build your image?

And: in which folder are you executing the `docker build` command? Make sure you execute it within the folder that holds the `Dockerfile` so that the relative paths match.

**Update**: I tried to reproduce your problem. What I did from within a temp folder:

```
mkdir -p a/b/c
echo "test" > a/b/c/test.txt
cat <<EOF > Dockerfile
FROM debian
ENV MYPATH /newdir
RUN mkdir $MYPATH
ADD ./a/b/c/* $MYPATH/
CMD cat $MYPATH/test.txt
EOF
docker build -t test .
docker run --rm -it test
```

That prints `test` as expected. The important part works: the `ADD ./a/b/c* $MYPATH`. The file at the end is found as its content `test` is displayed during runtime.

When I now change the path `./a/b/c/*` to something else, I get the `no such file or directory exists` error. When I leave the path as is and invoke `docker build` from a different folder than the temp folder where I placed the files the error is shown, too.